# Vim editor with Ubuntu

Tags: vim

I want to learn the `Vim` editor. Could anyone recommend me a good course on the web?

Thanks in advance!

**P.S.** I want if you could explain why it is a good course and if you learn with this course.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two web-sites that I recommend to get the basics:

- [opemvim](http://www.openvim.com/)
- [vim-adventures](http://vim-adventures.com/)

The first one is an interactive tutorial, it's short but it will cover all the basics, excellent for beginners and the second one is a small game which is quite fun.

Once you cover that, if you want to go a bit more beyond the basics and you are running linux just type `vimtutor` in the command line and follow the tutorial. Here is the man entry for [vimtutor](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/vimtutor1.html).

Enjoy!